# Spring RestTemplete get GeoJson

Tags: spring-mvc, geojson, resttemplate

How can I use Spring RestTemplate to get GeoJson into my controller? I need it to get GeoJson to my controller so I can pass it to a view where I will draw it on a map.

I tested it with String and get for object like so:

```
String featureCollection = restTemplate.getForObject(geoJsonUrl, String.class);
```

It works for now but what is a better way of doing so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of a RestTemplate message converter that directly supports GeoJson. However, you can try to use `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` to consume the resource as a Jackson [`JsonNode`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.0.2/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html). Then it will be easier to traverse the json structure.

```
JsonNode featureCollection = restTemplate.getForObject(geoJsonUrl, JsonNode.class);
```

By default `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` only supports the `application/json` media type. If the server is setting a different `Content-type`, then you may need to specify that. For example, the following sets the supported media type to `text/javascript`:

```
MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jackson = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
jackson.setSupportedMediaTypes(Collections.singletonList(new MediaType("text", "javascript")));
List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters = new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();
converters.add(jackson);
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(converters);
```